# Is there any in-built function/method to return, IActionResult/ActionResult instead of HttpResponseMessage in .Net Core 3.1

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi

My Action method is returning **HttpResponseMessage** but, I want to get rid off **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.WebApiCompatShim** NuGet Package (which is basically provided to bridge the gap while porting Asp.Net Web API code into .Net Core) and use **IActionResult/ActionResult** instead of **HttpResponseMessage**.

My Action method looks like this:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetTemplate")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetTemplate(string id) {
        var userAgent = this.Request.Headers.UserAgent;
        bool IsWindows = true;
        if(userAgent.ToString().ToLower().Contains("apple")) {
            IsWindows = false; //false
        }
        var template = await _templateService.GetTemplateContent(id);
        HttpResponseMessage responseMsg = new HttpResponseMessage();
        if(IsWindows) {
            responseMsg.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(template));
            responseMsg.RequestMessage = Request;
            responseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
        } else {
            responseMsg.Content = new ByteArrayContent(template.ContentBytes);
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment") { FileNameStar = template.Name };
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", template.Name);
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
            responseMsg.Content.Headers.ContentLength = template.ContentBytes.Length;
            responseMsg.RequestMessage = Request;
            responseMsg.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
        return (responseMsg);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you aren’t doing anything fancy there, you can translate your return object directly into corresponding action results here. In your case, you want a [`JsonResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.json?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_Controller_Json_System_Object_) and a [`FileResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.file?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_File_System_Byte___System_String_System_String_) with a custom response header:

```cs
[HttpGet]
[Route("GetTemplate")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetTemplate(string id)
{
    var userAgent = this.Request.Headers.UserAgent;
    bool IsWindows = !userAgent.ToString().ToLower().Contains("apple");

    var template = await _templateService.GetTemplateContent(id);
    if (IsWindows)
    {
        return Json(template);
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Headers.Add("x-filename", template.Name);
        return File(template.ContentBytes, "application/octet-stream", template.Name);
    }
}
```

There are a lot similar utility methods on the [`Controller`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller?view=aspnetcore-3.1#methods) and [`ControllerBase`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-3.1#methods) type that help you create a variety of different response messages. For most use cases, there should be a built-in way to produce the response.

Answer (score 0):

1stly change the signature of your action to this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTemplate
```

You will then return your data in the response something like this `return Ok(data)`. You do not have to serialize your data, you can send a POCO class. This would represent `.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK`

If you want to add extra headers to your response, you will do so using the `Response` field from `ControllerBase`. Eg. `Response.Headers.Add` for adding key value pairs to your Response header.